# XHTML 1.1 and Image Height

Tags: html

I'm trying to resize an image in an XHTML 1.1 web page based on browser's height. So in the stylesheet I have

```
img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but has no effect in Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Jason is giving the best answer but the standard response to your question is, without the complete markup or a link, anything else we say is just a wild guess as to the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That line means the height of the image should be 100% of it's containing area. Depending on your markup, this could simple be the images inherit height or the height of the parent element.